# Running CHAID on continuous predictors

Tags: python, decision-tree, spss-modeler

Please, did anyone try to run CHAID algorithm on continuous predictors ??

At first, I used SPSS Modeler and it worked fine.

but when I tried it on Python 3.6, it didn't work for me.

Thanks :)

P.S. CHAID package could be found here :
https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of that library.

It's usually better to post on the issues tab on the github repo as questions have more visibility there.

Unfortunately, with regards to continuous predictors, they need to be binned first before they can be run using CHAID. We haven't implemented a binning strategy as it's very subjective (SPSS makes a lot of decisions under the hood).